# Can I remove the clutch system from bike helmet?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, safety, helmets

I recently bought a Kali Chakra Plus helmet for my bike. [This](https://kaliprotectives.com/helmets/trail/chakra-plus) is the link with the specs.

It has the inner clutch system made from plastic in order to adjust the fit which is plastic and onto which the padding is placed. I want to remove the plastic clutch for traveling purposes (I need to put it inside a bag) and it looks like it can be removed but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know if it can be removed?

Below is the picture of the helmet from inside with the clutch painted in orange:[image]

Comment: Usually the straps can be removed (and importantly, put back in), but you'll have to try it and see, and use your own judgement.  It's not likely that anyone seeing your question has that particular helmet.

Comment: Does the clutch adjust interfere with fitting the helmet inside the helmet bag?    Does the clutch part fold into the helmet at all if you push it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean: is this particular system in this helmet *designed* to be user removable? Probably not.

If you mean *can* you remove it *and* put it back together correctly without compromising its function or safety? Maybe. You could figure out how to dissemble it and photo-document every step.

I'd personally figure out a different way to pack it, as that seems like much less hassle.